# Convert one-dimensional RGB byte array into c++ bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap

This question has been asked before on this site, but my problem is a little different and I cannot piece together other people's code to fit my goal. To make things better, the Windows documentation for `LockBits()`, `CreateBitmap()`, and many other possible relevant functions has no examples and barely even specifies what the parameters are.

What I'm trying to do is to create an image out of an array of bytes that represent the colors of the image. The array is three times as large as the number of pixels on the screen so that there is a red, green, and blue element for each pixel. Each pixel's color can be described as `RGB(x + (width * y), x + (width * y) + 1, x + (width * y) + 2)`, where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the point and `width` is the width of the image.

The last thing is that I would like to do it in C++ with standard libraries.

If it's not too much trouble, could anyone help me in this puzzle?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a bitmap, assuming its width is such that you don't need padding at the end of each line. What specifically are you having trouble with? There are many examples here and elsewhere on how to write bitmap files.

Comment: There is no C++ standard bitmap.  You appear to be on windows, and want some kind of windows platform dependent bitmap.  I would guess a DIB (device independent bitmap)?  What do you intend to do woth this bitmap?  Or do you want to create a .bmp file?

Comment: I do not wish to make a .bmp file, but rather a bitmap object. My bad for not clarifying! I am on windows, and I will write this bitmap to the screen every frame. I am doing this to essentially substitute SetPixel() for adjusting the three units of the byte array around (x + (width * y)), as, as I'm sure you know, SetPixel is slower than a mac.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I do not have a bitmap. I am trying to make a bitmap to write to the screen (a buffer dc, to be specific) and I'll need to do it quickly, as this will be the way I display polygons in real time. However, I do have a byte array with all the information I need for drawing the image, as well as the height and width of the image, which is static and identical to the dimensions of the window.

Comment: @Tex You're closer than you think. I don't have time to write a complete answer atm, but perhaps this will help. https://pastebin.com/Lwg87CSH Your image will probably be upside down with that code. If so, use `bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -pbm.height;` to make the bitmap right side up.

Comment: I'm really sorry for being a daft ****. I understand that a compatible dc is generated and associated with the bitmap that was created, then blit to the hdc. Some magic in CreateDIBSection is not immediately clear to me.